# What's the new before_create in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried using before_create:

> class Star < ActiveRecord::Base   before_create :add_to_total_stars
>
> Post Load (9.7ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id"
>   = ? ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]    (1.0ms)  rollback transaction NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for
>   nil:NilClass

But as you can see I'm getting an error.

What's the new before_create in Rails 4?

**EDIT:**

```
class Star < ActiveRecord::Base   before_create :add_to_total_stars

  belongs_to :starable, :polymorphic => true

  protected

  def add_to_total_stars
    if [Post].include?(starable.class)
      self.starable.update_column(:total_stars, starable.total_stars + self.number)
    end   end end

NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass    from /home/alex/rails/rating/app/models/star.rb:10:in `add_to_total_stars'  from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:377:in `_run__956917800__create__callbacks'    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'  from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:303:in `create_record'   from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `create_record'    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:466:in `create_or_update'  from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:299:in `block in create_or_update'   from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:383:in `_run__956917800__save__callbacks'  from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'  from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:299:in `create_or_update'    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:106:in `save'  from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'   from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:32:in `save'   from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block (2 levels) in save'     from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'   from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'     from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'   from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'  from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'  from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block in save'    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:281:in `rollback_active_record_state!'    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:269:in `save'     from (irb):5    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'     from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'  from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'  from bin/rails:4:in `require'   from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'1.9.3-p0 :006 > ^C
1.9.3-p0 :006 >  alex@alex-K43U:~/rails/rating$ rails c
```

Comment: What is `add_to_total_stars` implementation and your full error backtrace?

Comment: Your `starable.total_stars` call returns `nil` and that's why the error occurs.